# Using R Interactive graphs in Power BI with visNetwork

Tags: r, powerbi, visnetwork

Currently when I try to generate my R visual in Power BI using visNetwork (it works fine in R Studio), it tells me that no graph has been generated. Based on my research, it is my understanding that this is because of the fact that Power BI currently does not support HTML views, and my graph is generated in HTML form. Before I put this project on hold, however, I wanted to confirm this assumption of mine and see if there are any workarounds. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can built RHTML view in power BI.

so you get html view of your R visual

Comment: How can you display a RHTML in power bi from plotly?

Answer (score 0):

Copy/pasting the code that you have written in R into the Power Bi R script will not work.

The only way to show the visual into Power Bi is to first create an **application** of the R code. For more information about how to create a r-powered custom visual it is recommended that you have a look at this website: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/tree/master/RVisualTutorial/TutorialFunnelPlot.

In addition, the essence of creating a r powered custom visual with HTML output is to add the following code at the beginning of the script and at the end of the script:

```
# For Example:
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')

library(ggplot2)

############### Library Declarations ###############

libraryRequireInstall("ggplot2");
####################################################

################### Actual code ####################

# Enter your manipulation of the code in this section 
g <- ggplot(yourdata) 

############# Create and save widget ###############

internalSaveWidget(g, 'out.html');

####################################################
```

I hope this clarifies some things for you.

Good luck!